# npx react-native init AwesomeProject error enolocal

Tags: node.js, react-native, package.json, npx

i got an error while trying to create react native app using npx npx

> react-native init AwesomeProject

like the docs said. But i got an error messages

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from
> "Indigo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\3192" as it does not contain a
> package.json file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> C:\Users\Durio
> Indigo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-08T08_20_54_191Z-debug.log
> Install for react-native@latest failed with code 1

i know it's not from the npx because i tried to create react app with npx and it works. Am I the only one who had this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had you try `npm cache clear` and if using windows you can run command `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` in `Command promt` using `Run as Administrator`

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue, do nothing just a quick fix.

first, run the command `npm i react-native@latest -g` then create your project with your command i.e `npx react-native init myProject`

Comment: This is not truly a fix. It is simply using global react-native package instead of the one provided by npx.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in node which is caused by white space in user name between first-name and last-name in windows.

run the following command after replacing firstname with your windows user firstname in command prompt with administrator access

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

Answer (score 0):

we should check the android SDK path on environment variable. Make sure there is no white space on the SDK path and platform-tools path

Answer (score 0):

**For MAC users**

For the latest version, npm won't let you clear the cache. So to fix this issue, run;

```
npm cache verify
```

If throwing an error run this command (will be shown in the error too);

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/username/.npm"
```

After that, test whether the cache is verified or not by running the first command again.
If it worked, you are good to go. Run the react native cli command to create the new project and that should work fine.

```
npx react-native@latest init yourproject
```

Answer (score 0):

npx react-native init AwesomeProject

100% solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34918772)